# should the HQL query that is called of a specific domain be specific to that domain?

Tags: grails, hql

The grails documentation gives the following example for domain.executeQuery() method.

```
  Account.executeQuery("select distinct a.number from Account a")
```

In another place, I have seen the following command.

```
Registration.executeQuery(
            'select i.id from SaleInvoice i '
            + 'left join i.entries ie '
            + 'left join ie.discount d '
            + 'left join d.discountCode dc '
            );
```

It seems that the HQL query need not be specific to the domain class whose executeQuery() method we are calling. If so then it seems arbitrary and we can call executeQuery method of arbitrary domain class to execute arbitrary HQL queries. Please clear my misunderstanding if i have misunderstood the purpose of executeQuery(). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class that you call `executeQuery` (and `executeUpdate`, `withTransaction`, `withNewTransaction`, `withSession`, `withNewSession`) on has no impact on how the methods run. The methods probably should have been added to a `Gorm` class but instead were added to all domain classes.